# slack slash commands adding request url with query params

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm having an existing slack slash command "/myMeet" this is been configured to the backend with Request URL "https://slack-api.myTestCompany.com/slack".

Now i have re-written my backend, and i want to support both existing backend and new-backend, so only way i can differentiate is with the 
Request URL configured in slack admin portal "https://slack-api.myTestCompany.com/slack". so my doubt here is can slack slash commands Request URL support query parameter?

For eg: request url - "https://slack-api.myTestCompany.com/slack?appVersion=old"

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add query params to your Slash Command's request URL and the API will honor that.